# From "Display Name" not working - Postfix/Dovecot

Tags: mysql, email, postfix, dovecot, headers

Working with Dovecot, Postfix and MySQL to send email from my web server (at `example@mywebsite.com`) but what shows up in the inbox is `example` instead of the display name I put into the email client (tried Thunderbird and Evolution with same results).

In the From address bar, it shows what I want others to see (`Example Email <example@mywebsite.com>`) but I only get the username from the address to be seen in the From header when it shows up (just `example`).

Probably an easy fix, but Googling doesn't seem to show the problem I'm having.

Would appreciate!

EDIT:

Source from a sent email:

```
Message-ID: <87168f7ddaf6ce4ca4c21e6170cfff3bad32d807.camel@examplewebsite.com>
Subject: Test
From: Info | Example Website <info@examplewebsite.com>
Reply-To: info@examplewebsite.com
To: johndoe@example.com
Date: Tue, 09 Aug 2022 16:43:52 -0500
Organization: My Company, LLC
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
User-Agent: Evolution 3.44.1-0ubuntu1 
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Evolution-Identity: 0b6d91da4aa7ee3ac76e579ff7d40d0520a3d7a9
X-Evolution-Fcc: folder://668759784892638f7b10840d2215b726933b1858/Sent
X-Evolution-Transport: 2413e8d652e6e8743ee6c8043f7c35c9e2468093
X-Evolution-Source: 

Test message
```

Comment: Please provide your configuration. Otherwise it's just blind guessing.

Comment: That could get pretty lengthy.  Essentially, I used Linode's guide to setting up mail with Postfix, Dovecot, MySQL on this site:  https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql/

Comment: I'd like to add the configs but there are so many, I'm afraid of dropping a mess here and would rather narrow it down to a specific file maybe

Comment: That's not helpful. We don't know the base config you started with, we don't know which steps of the guide you did and which you didn't (on purpose or not). If you want help, provide your config. Personally, if it's always `example` that shows up my first step would be to grep the config for `example`.

Comment: Will try to go through it again and post if I find something relevant

Comment: Maybe you just did not setup your mail client as intended? Use "Show Source" and quote the "From:" header for us.

Comment: Just added the source

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you modify your client settings until the *display name* part of your header appears quoted in the message source. So instead of this:

```
From: Info | Example Website <info@website.example>
```

What you want to be transmitted is this:

```
From: "Info | Example Website" <info@website.example>
```

That will get you more or less consistent display in line with [RFC5322 Section 3.2.4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322#section-3.2.4).

Comment: But I do not want to let users specify their display name